# Неправильно отображаются числа из подключенного шрифта

Tags: шрифты

Подключил шрифт на сайт TrajanPro3-Regular

```
@font-face {
font-family: Trajan;
src: url(../fonts/Trajan/TrajanPro3-Regular.eot);
src: url(../fonts/Trajan/TrajanPro3-Regular.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), 
url(../fonts/Trajan/TrajanPro3-Regular.woff) format("woff"), 
url(../fonts/Trajan/TrajanPro3-Regular.ttf) format("truetype"), 
url(../fonts/Trajan/TrajanPro3-Regular.svg) format("svg");  
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
unicode-range: U+0-10FFFF;
```

}

И дело в том, что число "3" - выводится не так, как должно выводить.
А все остальные числа - выводит как нужно.

Вывожу на сайте такой текст:
**1234567890**

Выводит вот как:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот открыл файл для просмотра TrajanPro3-Regular.ttf, и в файле выводит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, число "3" - выводится не так, как в подключаемом файле выводится.
Почему так:?

---

Установил шрифт из этого-же файла  в систему, и в фотошопе тройка отображается правильно, а на сайтах - нет.

Comment: Для справки: бывают большие и маленькие не только буквы, но и... цифры!

Comment: Ну цифры то нельзя же сделать большими или маленькими... там только font-size изменяет их

Comment: Смешной вы, вам говорят, а вы отрицаете... https://www.paratype.ru/help/term/terms.asp?code=342

Comment: А использовать как его в итоге?  В фш в любом регистре пишу - выводит верно, а как на сайте вывести правильно?